# Catch .bat file variables in .txt file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I have a simple question.

Is it possible to pass variables from .bat file to .txt file? All I can find online is to append variables at the end of the file or override the whole .txt file.
Is it possible to leave {0}, {1} variable catchers or something similar in a .txt file, so I could with a .bat command send variables to a .txt file for these specific places when running it?

Just a general wondering, if it is possible or the correct way is to override the .txt file and just include my variables in these places myself.

Comment: It's possible to substitute batch variables for specific strings in a text file template, but the capacity is limited and awkward to use. Provided the required text is free of "poison characters" (those with a special meaning to `cmd`), this *can* be done, but it's probably easier to use a tool built for the job like `sed` or `(g)awk`. Nevertheless, for simple substitutions, yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can "abuse" the variable expansion process in batch files to get something similar

*template.txt*

```
The element !data1! refers to !data2!

Also, the element !data3! points to !data4!


You will need to escape exclamations
    Escaped exclamation     : ^!
    Non escaped exclamation : !

;
;           !data4!
;
```

*process.cmd*

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Define the set of data that will be replaced
    set "data1=TEST"
    set "data2=This is the data in || TEST ||"

    set "data3=Another test!"
    set "data4=< data inside [Another test!]>"

    rem Read template (uses findstr /n to retrieve empty lines)
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "template.txt"') do (
        rem Retrieve line
        set "line=%%a" 

        rem To retrieve the data in line var we need delayed expansion
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

        rem Output template line after removing initial numbers
        rem On empty lines the for command "fails". This is detected and 
        rem handled by echoing an empty line
        (for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%b in ("!line:*:=!") do echo(%%b)||echo(

        rem Cancel delayed expansion
        endlocal
    )
```

*console output*

```
W:\45820941>process
The element TEST refers to This is the data in || TEST ||

Also, the element Another test! points to < data inside [Another test!]>


You will need to escape exclamations
    Escaped exclamation     : !
    Non escaped exclamation :

;
;           < data inside [Another test!]>
;

W:\45820941>
```